# find out which program pops up a command line window

Tags: windows-10

I have windows 10 home and from time to time I see a command line window popping up for less than a second. I want to find out which process is causing that. It's not very often that this window pops up so I need some tool that can run for a long time.

Does anyone have a good idea?

Regards
Tobias

Comment: @Run5k thx for bringing that up. I tried the solution there - I'll see whether that helps or not.

Comment: [Log of all applications that run or running manually on PC with start/end time](//superuser.com/q/898066)

Comment: @DavidPostill another great answer. Thank you!